# Application crash after approved

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I got my application approved on app store.

But due to some change in the feed I am using my app is crashing now. What am I supposed to do now?

Giving an update will take 7 days for apple to approve and I will get bad reviews if any one downloads it in between.

What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

1. Fix the feed.
2. Remove the app from sale until you fixed the bug and the update is approved.
3. Remove the app from sale until you fixed the bug and the update is approved and request a [speedy review](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewteam/).

To remove a App from sale, go to the  `Rights and Pricing` of that app in iTunnesConnect and set the `Availability Date` in the future. this will remove the app from sale. Just put the date back to now to make it available again.

Comment: can u please tell me how to remove it from sale

Comment: so i just deselected all the countries in rights and pricing. if i update it and select all the countries after apple approves it.Will it work?

Comment: No set the `Availability Date` in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for an expedited review (http://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewteam/), if you haven't abused of it yet and have real reasons (as it seems) to ask for it, they will review your App in between 1 and 3 days... :)

If you want to stop selling your App while it is happening, you can go to the Pricing menu in iTunes Connect and remove all the countries available...

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit an expedited review request. From my personal experience I've generally pushed these out within 24 hours. Usually Apple does these as a one time exception, and is supposed to be used once in a great while. I've done 4 total in 2 years. Anyhow, since there is contact information on the website, if users download and contact you reply back that there are pending updates, and will be out shortly.

You could go through pausing delivery of app until ready, etc, etc. Availability can be changed and automated via dates. You can remove from countries available.

Here is link for expedited review. You'll need your App ID and Name, etc.
http://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewteam/